# ExtJS-6 Dataview Extension Issue

Tags: events, extjs, dataview

I have extended a view.View to isolate just some of the events that are fired from the store (code is found at https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1777)

The problem I am having is that when a record is added, it should fire a custom event for the controller to pick up; however, I am getting an error in the console

`TypeError: owner.up is not a function`

I am somewhat at an impasse at this point as I have attempted debugging the issue and the only thing I can come up with is that the error is occurring at the:

```
this.fireEventArgs('added',[...]);
```

In the globals.AltStdView class.  Can someone please advise me on what I am incorrectly doing?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `me.getView.dataView.store.add(record);` is wrong. `getView` is supposed to be a method.

Secondly, `added` is already an event used by the framework for components. You should pick a different name.

Comment: The getview() issue was a typo on my part - not sure why the corrected fiddle wasn't published; Many thanks to you and JChap for pointing out the "added" event. Worked as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of Issues here,

- As @Evan mentioned, me.getView is a function. So it should be me.getView().
- You are firing an "added" event which is actually inbuilt event of DataView and because of this listeners of added event are throwing errors as event args different. So i renamed the event to 'recordadded'

After applying the above fixes, here is the working fiddle.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/177v

Comment: The getview() issue was a typo on my part - not sure why the corrected fiddle wasn't published; Many thanks to you and Evan for pointing out the "added" event.  Worked as expected now.